# Excel PivotTable: Column counting specific name and clustered column chart

Tags: excel, excel-charts, excel-pivot

I have a table from which I want to make a PivotTable.

| Date | Option | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09-05-2023 | A | 1 |
| 15-05-2023 | B | 2 |
| 17-05-2023 | C | 3 |
| 23-05-2023 | A | 4 |
| 31-05-2023 | A | 1 |
| 01-06-2023 | B | 4 |
| 01-06-2023 | C | 2 |
| 12-06-2023 | A | 1 |
| 12-07-2023 | B | 2 |

I want the PivotTable to be grouped in years/months (that's not a problem) but I also want to count per months how many options are present. So, have 3 columns available. Each counting their own type of option. It should look like this:

[image: PivotTable]

However, I cannot get it to work (the picture is self made, not automatic PivotTable). Is it possible to get this to work, without alternating or adding extra columns to the existing source table? But manage it within the PivotTable itself.

And another thing I would like to do, is to make a clustered column chart for all the 4 types per month. Like the example chart below. With 1/2/3/4 instead of east/west/north/south. And the amount per month on the y-axis instead of dollars.

[image: Example Clustered column chart]